# Access denied for Users after database migration from SP2010 to SP2013

Tags: powershell, migration, claims-based-auth, access-denied, classic-mode-auth

After content DB migration from SP2010 to SP2013, a number of users who has permission to access cannot access to the SharePoint 2013 site. The error message given is "Access Denied". I have confirmed the permission on the site but it says the user has proper permission for the site.

I suspected that it is a problem of authentication mode between two environments because SP2010 is Classic mode and SP2013 is Claims mode.

```
    $wa = Get-SPWebApplication -identity http://YourSiteHere

    $wa.MigrateUsers($true)

    $wa.Update()
```

However, above Powershell script does not solve the problem yet. Do you have any other clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all users getting the access deneid or only set of user getting access denied on a site collection?

Comment: Actually, most users who are not a member of site collection admin groups

Comment: did you configure the object cache settings at web application level( this is most common reason) for access denied after migration....